# In Vulgate, Matthaeus 4:23, it says "et prædicans Evangelium regni". Shouldn't it be "regno" (dative) rather than "regni" (genitive)?

Tags: syntax, morphology, vulgata, second-declension, bible

In Vulgate, Matthaeus 4:23, it says "et prædicans Evangelium regni". Shouldn't it be "regno" (dative) rather than "regni" (genitive)? He was talking the gospel TO the kingdom, not the gospel OF the kingdom.

Comment: In most translations I know and in Catholic and many other Christian theologies, it is the Gospel/good news of (i.e., about) the Kingdom (of Heavens/of God). Are you concerned about a specific translation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Latin is a pretty literal translation of the Greek:

> καὶ κηρύσσων τὸ εὐαγγέλιον **τῆς βασιλείας**

"τῆς βασιλείας" (tēs basileias) is genitive, not dative. He is preaching the Gospel **of the kingdom**, not preaching the Gospel **to the kingdom.**

This makes sense. The "kingdom" in question--as is clear from many other passages throughout the New Testament--is the "kingdom of Heaven" (ἡ βασιλεία τῶν οὐρανῶν) or (as Mark and Luke prefer to say) the "kingdom of God" (ἡ βασιλεία τοῦ Θεοῦ). It is the message, not the recipient.

A review of [several English translations](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Matthew%204:23) makes it pretty clear that this hasn't been a matter of dispute.

Comment: ⋯ or rather the [kingdom of Heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_heaven_(Gospel_of_Matthew)) (regnum caelorum), which is presumably the same thing.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I never noticed this difference in word choice among the three synoptic Gospels!